# Inserting PDFs into Stack Exchange posts inline

Tags: support, latex, pdf

Is it possible to insert PDFs into Stack Exchange posts, or do I have to convert them to images first?

Specifically, I'd like to insert a PDF on [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). My latex code (.tex) compiles to PDF and I want to **display** both in a post (so I'm not interested in uploading the file and having it as an attachment to my post).

Comment: Judging by the few posts I examined on [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), the answer seems to be "You have to convert them to images first"

Comment: This seems to be about inserting a PDF for display rather than attaching a PDF for download so the duplicate does not seem to apply.